# Setting up Intel RST on Ubuntu 12.10

Tags: ubuntu, software-raid, intel-rst

I want to know if it is possible to set up caching using my notebooks mSSD that runs ubuntu 12.10 and Win 7 on the HDD. I use ubuntu much more and would prefer to cache files that it uses rather than cache windows.

I found [this PDF](http://download.intel.com/design/intarch/PAPERS/326024.pdf) on the intel site that says it is possible.

I want to know if anyone has done this? How did you manage it?

If there is a tutorial somewhere then please do point me to it.

Answer (score 4):

The SSD caching capabilities in the current generation of Intel's RST (on the H77, Q77 and Z77/Z79 chipsets) can only be used through the Windows driver.  Linux support, as noted by the PDF, is provided by the native Linux tools.  There is no separate Intel-provided driver for RST on Linux.

For SSD caching on Linux, you should look at Linux-native solutions like [flashcache](https://github.com/facebook/flashcache) or [bcache](http://bcache.evilpiepirate.org/).  See also, [flashcache & bcache benchmarking](http://www.accelcloud.com/2012/04/18/linux-flashcache-and-bcache-performance-testing/).

Comment: Hey thanks. Had come accross both flashcache and bcache and they can do the job, but have you tried to do this? Do you have any idea how? Also, would you have any idea how to use the native linux tools (MD RAID is actually intel supported) for setting up something like RST?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to get my hands on a spare SSD for long enough to try them out.

Comment: With regards to using mdadm to manage an RST array, I haven't actually needed to do so yet.  I have about 30 systems running RST RAID 1, most are running Windows, and I've only ever needed to worry about managing or rebuilding an array once or twice in the past few years.  Last time I tried was with a very old distribution with only dmraid support instead of md support.

Comment: Wow thanks for this, I've been looking for a Linux-compatible alternative to Intel's RST for a little while... This is particularly interesting since it doesn't require a particular chipset to function!

Comment: I have been looking for this for a very long while - and was starting to think of switching back to Windows if there wasn't anything. Thanks for keeping me on Linux!